# How to choose between "work day" vs "working day"

Tags: word-choice

For business days, I see both 'work day' and 'working day'. Which one is correct? Also asking between 'work hours' vs 'working hours'.

Context: I have 5 work/working/business days. My work/working/business hours are 7 per day.

Comment: You have to give us the context.  Ideally, you would give us a sentence so we can see exactly what you're trying to express.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a *work day* is a day on which you work, while the *working day* is that part of the day when you're at work: "my work days are Monday to Friday: at the end of the working day I go straight home to dinner".

*Working hours* can be used to be more specific: "working hours are 9-5". A total number of working hours per day is often used in flexible working systems with *core hours*, i.e. hours when everyone is expected to be in: "working hours: 37.5 per week, core hours 10-4" (typical in a job specification). *Work hours* isn't as common but means the same.

*Business hours*, as the name suggests, apply to the business rather than its staff, like opening hours for a shop; they are likely to be longer than any individual's working hours.

Some of this may be biased towards British usage, but not intentionally.

Comment: In BrE, a "work day" is not a common phrase in my impression, whereas "working day" is mostly used to mean equally "a day on which work is done/business conducted" and "the hours in a day during which work is done", with context determining the appropriate meaning.

Comment: I get in trouble when I say why I downvote, but I still can't bring myself not to say why I do so. (1) 'Some of this may be biased towards British usage, but not intentionally.' screams of opinion rather than sound analysis. (2) Dictionaries give entries for 'workday' and 'working day', and show that usages are inconsistent. The **question** should give these, never mind any answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the key here is **usage** which dictionaries do a poor job of capturing due to limited space - and if they did it would be general refernce.  I can make allowances as best I can but place a warning in there.  I know we've come at this from opposite viewpoints in the past, and I don't mind the disagreement on that basis.  But I would like to see if you know of a dictionary that captures this much detail.

Comment: @Steve You don't often need to define the work(ing) days of the week as they're normally assumed. The few occasions you do need this use, "working day"+context works, as does "work day"; I've seen both

Comment: @ChrisH thanks, though i don't understand the difference between work day and working day as u explained. can't i say: "my work days are Monday to Friday: at the end of the work day I go straight home to dinner"?

Comment: @feynman, it's not clear cut, so yes you can, and you'd be understood perfectly. Without carrying out a survey, it appears less common, and it seems less natural to me.

Comment: @ChrisH, you don't normally need to define the working days of the week, but you often need to define how many working days something takes - such as "cheques clear in three working days".

Comment: @Steve another useful  definition I hadn't covered

Comment: The fact that 'Dictionaries give entries for 'workday' and 'working day', and show that usages are inconsistent' should be given in a scholarly answer (though as I said, OP should have shown research). Different dictionaries include or omit senses; this is important, as they research corpora. I doubt whether many people giving 'answers' do. Though COCA, and Google Books, are available.

Comment: People use both interchangeably.  Covering letter became cover letter; working place became work place, but waiting shed has not become wait-shed?! A difference possibly is each word of the pairs - covering & cover, working & work - do function like nouns/verbal nouns. In case of waiting & wait, former is a (verbal)noun and the latter a verb. Not sure if this comment justifies.

Answer (score 0):

A quick visit to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) yields the following entries:

> **workday** *n* (13c) **1 :** a day on which work is performed as distinguished from a day off **2 :** the period of time in a day during which work is performed — **workday** *adj*
>
> ...
>
> **working day** *n* (15c) : WORKDAY

In other words, according to this general-reference resource, the noun *workday* and the noun phrase *working day* are interchangeable, meaning that both definitions that MW gives for *workday* also apply to *working day*.

MW asserts that *workday* is roughly two centuries older than *working day*, but both terms have been in use for more than 500 years. *Workday* may be more firmly established than *working day* as an adjective, but the absence of "— **working day** *adj*" from the dictionary's entry for *working day* should not, I think, be taken as a denial that *working day* can appear as a modifier in expressions such as "working day routine"; indeed, a Google Books search finds multiple instances of that particular phrase, sometimes with the modifier [hyphenated (as "working-day routine")](https://books.google.com/books?id=UywjAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA235&dq=%22working+day+routine%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinjvvb6e7tAhUbH80KHRSjD5IQ6AEwB3oECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22working%20day%20routine%22&f=false) and sometimes with it [unhyphenated (as "working day routine")](https://books.google.com/books?id=b4dgHsI76fAC&pg=PA279&dq=%22working+day+routine%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinjvvb6e7tAhUbH80KHRSjD5IQ6AEwCHoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22working%20day%20routine%22&f=false).

The Ngram chart for "working day" (blue line) versus "work day" (red line) versus "workday" (green line) for the period 1550–2019 shows a fair amount of variability in the various terms' popularity over the years:

[image]

Most notably, *working day* enjoyed a much more dramatic increase in frequency of use from about 1820 until about 1920 than did *work day* and *workday*, but in recent decades its advantage over *workday* has vanished.

Comment: Interestingly the option in the question (work day) which has been described, controversially, as a primarily American usage in comments and answers above shows as consistently less common than "working day" in your NGRAM.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that they are virtually interchangeable.

However in composite nouns involving adjectival "...ing words" there is a tendency for Americans to drop in "...ing" part. Hence in the USA you hear them talk about ***fry pans*** (UK frying pans), ***swim shorts*** (UK swimming shorts), ***file cabinets*** (UK filing cabinets), ***a lead role*** (UK leading role) and hence ***work day*** (UK working day).

I think it is largely a difference between American and British treatment.

Comment: I've just largely cut-and-pasted from above. 'I get in trouble when I say why I downvote, but I still can't bring myself not to say why I do so. (1) No references. (2) Dictionaries give entries for 'workday' and 'working day', and show that usages are inconsistent. The question should give these, never mind any answer.' // eg [CollinsCoBuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/working-day):1. A _working day_ is the amount of time during a normal day that you spend doing your job.
[mainly British]. Can a 'workday' have this sense? In the UK?

Comment: You are right in that "work day", even within the UK,  CAN have a semantic difference from "working day". Though as Steve points out in his comment, the latter can be used to imply a day on which work is done - "Monday's a bank holiday, but Tuesday's a normal working day". I still think the overriding distinction here is that between American use and our own.

Comment: What you say contradicts (and corrects) 'The answer is that they are virtually interchangeable' (the reason for the downvote, of course).

Comment: Interchangeable in mid-Atlantic.

Comment: When crossing the International Working Date Line?