# When to use "work day" vs "workday"

Tags: word-choice

When should I use “work day” and when should I use “workday”? Is this a matter of style or are there certain grammatical cues that dictate one versus the other?

I see the Google Books Ngram Viewer logs the terms at roughly the same usage in printed books until 1970, when the single-word form starts a steady linear gain while the two-word form stays relatively level. The hyphenated “work-day” form is dead last, quite notably behind the others since the 1940s:

[image: Google Books Ngram comparison: a graph of relative popularity of these terms, 1900-2008]

Microsoft Office’s grammar suggestions always head to “workday”, though they’re not (yet‽) an authority here. (Yes, I know MS and others are making strong pushes towards certain styles under the guise of grammar corrections. I’m happy to see a linked rant on this topic, but let’s keep that as an aside.)

(See also this related but different [question about “work day” vs “working day”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/502139/112762).)

Comment: Note that the "work day" instances are likely contaminated by false positives that don't mean the same as "workday". For example: "He had to work day in and day out."  So "workday" is certainly even more dominant than your Ngram result would suggest.

Comment: [This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_DET_+workday%2C_DET_+work+day%2C_PRON_+workday%2C_PRON_+work+day%2C_ADJ_+workday%2C_ADJ_+work+day&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_DET_%20workday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20work%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_PRON_%20workday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_PRON_%20work%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_ADJ_%20workday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_ADJ_%20work%20day%3B%2Cc0) should eliminate most of the false positives.